# Запрос в БД без перезагрузки страницы

Tags: css, javascript, html, php, mysql

Кто может подсказать наилучший вариант передачи данных в БД без перезагрузки страницы.

Вот, например, мой наихудший вариант:

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
function senddata() {
$.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  url: "senddata.php",
  data: { name: $('#pagename').val(), url:$('#pagelink').val()},
  success: function(data){notification('Страница создана')}
  }
  )}

</script>
```

В отдельном файле `senddata.php` находится зам запрос на добавление инфы в БД.
В данном варианте сообщение "Страница создана" вылетает не зависимо от того, было добавлена инфа в БД или нет, а вылетает оно в зависимости от того, был ли отправлен запрос к файлу `senddata.php` или нет. Поэтому независимо, была ли запись в БД или нет, он все равно выдает сообщение "Страница создана".

Comment: Для этого есть гугл.

Comment: @kostya, судя по аватаре вы хацкер. Хацкеры должны и так все знать, по дефолту. Тем более не задавать такие простые вопросы.

Comment: Всем спасибо за ответы. Все же лучше будет 
    
    success: function(data){$('#alert').html(data)}

Таким образом ответ на sql запрос будет подгружаться в контейнер с айдишником #alert.

Ну а с sql запросом уже достаточно вариаций.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

После добавления в senddata.php сделай COUNT запрос к базе по параметрам, которые должен был добавить. И если выводит единицу, то значит, что данные добавлены, если ноль, то нет.

```
mysql_result(mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `baza` WHERE `name` = $_POST['name'] AND `url` = $_POST['url']"), 0);
```

что-то типа такого

Answer (score 1):

```
    $.post("senddata.php", {name: $('#pagename').val(), url:$('#pagelink').val() },
   function(data) {
     alert("Data Loaded: " + data);
   });
```

Answer (score 0):

Да, все так и происходит. Только все же стоит проверять создана ли запись и вернуть результат из senddata.php. Аргумент data, в твоем случае, как раз содержит все, что отдает твой скрипт записи в базу.

Comment: Как проверить, создана ли запись в БД ?

Comment: открыть файл базы и просмотреть, или просмотреть в phpMyAdmin, или сделать запрос на вывод из базы этой записи

Comment: на php функция mysql_last_insert_id($result) возвратить id вставленной записи, или null если вставка не удалась. Более наглядно:

$result = mysql_query("insert into someTable someValues");
$id = mysql_last_insert_id($result);
if($id) return true;
return false;

Answer (score -1):

Когда я делал подобную штуку, в качестве ответа я передавал своеобразный код состояния.
В твоём случае сделал бы так же, т.е. страница senddata.php выводит сообщение об удачной или не удачной записи данных(в моём случае это было 1 или 0). А потом обрабатываешь с помощью js это сообщение.

Comment: Подскажи как.

Потому что страница senddata у меня всегда выводит сообщение об удачной записи, не зависимо от того была ли добавлена запись в БД или нет.